# Need advice on building SEO urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So the thing is i try to build my own webpage/cms and stuff. Everything works great, but now i want to optimize it up a nich.
And i'm going for SEO friendly urls at this time. For people who will suggest "use framework" i'll minus rep because you can't learn php just by using framework ( tho frameworks are very good and i'll move on them later ).

So the situation is as follows:
I have pages like my_profile.php and index.php?deal=39 and so forth.
I know i need to use mod_rewrite and i have a little expierence with it.
I know that you can make use of GET params in mod_rewrite.

Also if i have url like www.example.com/index.php?id=88 how do i make those in www.example.com/very-cool-url

So generally any good advice is apriciated on how to proceed.

Comment: While I understand your point about frameworks, it's more polite (and more productive) to *ask* people not to suggest something than to *threaten* to "minus rep".

Comment: +1 for learning language. Soon you will understand it better than 99% of folks who answers here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enought for you to start with.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Basically, now you can type something like

```
example.com/contacts/john
```

and make use of PHP to fetch the parameters, like

```
$params = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

**Note that** this code wasn't tested, and there's a LOT more to it than just this.

Comment: ... and then go nuts with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: I've always preferred `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?request=$1` myself. Seems cleaner somehow.

Comment: Thanks that will get me busy for some time :)